# XOR operation and BitCount in Java on Long variables returns java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, long-integer, xor, hamming-distance, bitcount

I am trying to do a XOR operation on two 64 bits Long variables in Java.
The problem is that it fails when I add more than 16 bits in a variable.

For instance this works and returns 7:

```
Long h1 = Long.parseLong("1100001101001101");
Long h2 = Long.parseLong("1100001101000001");
System.out.println(Long.bitCount(h1 ^ h2));
```

If I increase the value of h1 and h2 to:

```
Long h1 = Long.parseLong("11000110000110100110101101001101");
Long h2 = Long.parseLong("11000011100001101001101101000001");
```

I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11000110000110100110101101001101"
>           at
>  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>           at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
>           at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)

Same if I double it (64 bits what I would want to compute):

```
Long h1 = Long.parseLong("1100011100011000011010011010110100110110000110100110101101001101");
Long h2 = Long.parseLong("1100001110001100001101001101011010011011100001101001101101000001");
```

Any help on why this fails above 16 bits?

Comment: `Long.parseLong(String)` equals `parseLong(s, 10)`,

Comment: Documentation of [parseLong(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)): "Parses the string argument as a signed **decimal** long." (not binary)

Answer (score 6):

`Long.parseLong("11000110000110100110101101001101")` attempts to parse the `String` as decimal number, and this number is too large to fit in a `long` variable.

To parse the `String` as a binary number you need to specify the radix:

```
Long.parseLong("11000110000110100110101101001101",2);
```

BTW, `Long.parseLong` returns a `long`, so I'd either assign it to a `long`:

```
long h1 = Long.parseLong("11000110000110100110101101001101",2);
```

or use `Long.valueOf`:

```
Long h1 = Long.valueOf("11000110000110100110101101001101",2);
```

Comment: Thanks. But this fails for 64 bits:

long h1 = Long.parseLong("1100110000111000011010011011010011010011100001101001101101001101", 2);
        long h2 = Long.parseLong("1101110000111000011010011011010011011000011010011010001101000001", 2);

Returns same error...

Comment: @c1377554 well, you can't pass more than 63 bits. The highest bit in `long` is the sign bit, and `parseLong` doesn't take a 2's complement String. If you want to parse a negative number, you should pass a number with at most 63 bits prefixed by a '-'

Answer (score 0):

Convert this binary string to a number and then do the XOR.
like convert 0110 -> 6, 1000 -> 8 and so on...
then it won't give any exception.

```
public class Bin2Num {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long num1 = Bin2Num.funcBin2Long(args[0]);
        long num2 = funcBin2Long(args[1]);

        System.out.println("Num1 : " + num1);
        System.out.println("Num2 : " + num2);
        System.out.println("Num1 XOR num2 : " + (long)(num1 ^ num2));
    }

    public static long funcBin2Long(String str) {
        long answer = 0;
        for(int i = str.length() - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) == '1') answer += Math.pow(2, j);
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```